Android Compose: LazyVerticalGrid throws error when "verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())" is applied
My code:
class AppDrawer(private val context: Context){
    lateinit var listener: () -> Unit
    private val pm: PackageManager = context.packageManager
    private var appPrerender: List<AppPrerender>?=null;
    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { // In a CoroutineScope due to performance reasons
            appPrerender = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).toList()
                .filter {
                    pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(it.packageName) != null
                }
                .map {
                    AppPrerender(it.loadLabel(pm).toString(), it.loadIcon(pm).toBitmap(100, 100).asImageBitmap(), it.packageName) {
                        context.startActivity(
                            pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(it.packageName)
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    @Composable
    fun Compose() {
            LazyVerticalGrid(GridCells.Fixed(6),
                Modifier
//                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {

                if (appPrerender != null) {
                    items(appPrerender!!, key = { it.packageName }) {
                        it.Render()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
class AppPrerender(private val name: String, private val icon: ImageBitmap, val packageName: String, private val launch: ()->Unit){
    @Composable
    fun Render(){
        App(name, icon, launch)
    }
}

@Composable
fun App(name: String, icon: ImageBitmap, launch: ()->Unit){
    Image(icon, contentDescription = name, Modifier.padding(0.dp, 20.dp).clickable { launch() })
}

The layout implementation is at so no scrollable content above
This is the layout, as you can see, no scrollable components above nor below.
I always seam to recive the:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
                 Process: com.myxoz.home, PID: 32177
                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.

I added the
verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) 
cause the scrolling was very choppy, but i can't get it to work, if i comment it in, the app will crash
I also tried to set a fixed height (as recomended) but it doesnt seam to change anything

Lazy layouts (including the grid) already contain the scroll ability. I think the error is due to you putting 2 scroll states "on top of one another". Without it, it should still be scrollable vertically.
If this still does not solve your problem, I would suggest to use other non-lazy layouts as a debug tool, see if the error persists, and if so look where it originates.

Well, yes this is a solution, but I did it to reduce the lag, is there a better way to reduce the lag? The scrolling is very choppy

I think scrolling is "choppy", as you put it, due to the number of recompositions of the composable (check in layout inspector to verify). there are multiple ways to reduce the number of unnecessary recompositions, such as the use of @Immutable, derivedStateOf etc. I am almost certain this is the case in your scenario

As a general rule, I think its almost always safe to assume that what was provided to you by the framework (in our case Jetpack Compose) is much more efficient than what you or I are writing (at least because it was excessively tested before it saw the light of day), so dont let your FIRST solution to a problem you are having be "well, this method they provided is not very efficient, I can make something better"

Thats a very valid argument espacialy always safe to assume that what was provided...is much more efficient how would you optimize the scrolling tho?
I'm pretty new to compose so I dont really know about those modifiers, i now added
@Stable     fun Compose() {         val hiddenApps = remember {             this.hiddenApps.toMutableStateList()         }         rerenderHidden={hiddenApps.clear(); hiddenApps.addAll(this.hiddenApps)}
My code altered a bit and while i checked, it doesnt seam to recompose on scroll, it's still choppy, even with my Grid = Column and Row solution.

It must recompose, the question is how many times. if it recomposes on every twitch of the scroll, then you probably did something wrong in terms of optimization (or didnt do it at all). The one time I had this problem, I fixed it using derivedStateOf. I had a method of computation which calculated something continuously, though it didnt have to. When I used the derived state, it dropped my recomposition number from hundreds to around 10 (for a certain amount of scrolling

I don't know, it didn't fix it for me. I added a println to see how often it recomposes and it's 4 times, but this shouldn't matter for the lagginess of the scrollling, as it doesn't recompose on scroll, it works fine for me, could be better, could be worse, thanks for your help
